# Android Google Drive Integration Not Working For Some Users

Tags: android, google-drive-api

We have Android App integrating with Google Drive to upload and download files with Google Drive. We are able to upload files and download files successfully. And we tested in different phones/tablets with 2.3.x, 3.1.x, 4.1.x and 4.2.x. We think configuration and setup may be OK. However some users (we know some of them use 4.1.x and 4.2.x) keep getting the following error. We cannot figure out what the problem is. Please help.

```
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): {
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622):   "code": 403,
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622):   "errors": [
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622):     {
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622):       "domain": "usageLimits",
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622):       "message": "Access Not Configured",
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622):       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622):     }
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622):   ],
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622):   "message": "Access Not Configured"
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): }
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:314)
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1060)
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): at com.expensemanager.pro.GoogleDrive$14.run(GoogleDrive.java:419)
07-30 20:45:00.467: W/System.err(24622): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't setup your project properly. For Android apps, APIs console check if your **package name** and **certificate SHA1 fingerprint** matches with information you provided. Please double check if all of your package name and signing certificate fingerprint always matches with your configuration. Here is some [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android#step_2_enable_the_drive_api) about how to configure your project.